# Remove duplicate values in subgroups in r

Tags: r

I have a following data.frame:

```
dataFrame <- data.frame(sent = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,5), word = c("good printer","bad printer","wireless easy","amazing friendly",
                                                          "great friendly","quite vibrant nice","well vibrant","no vibrant",
                                                          "great notebook","nice car"),val = c(1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
                    extract = c("printer","printer","wireless","friendly","friendly","vibrant","vibrant","vibrant","notebook","car"))
```

which looks like below:

```
  sent          word     val  extract
   1       good printer   1  printer
   1        bad printer  -1  printer
   1      wireless easy   1 wireless
   2   amazing friendly   1 friendly
   2     great friendly   1 friendly
   3 quite vibrant nice   1  vibrant
   3       well vibrant   1  vibrant
   3   horrible vibrant  -1  vibrant
   4     great notebook   1 notebook
   5           nice car   1      car
```

and I'm struggling with removing of duplicates in each subgroup. So if the values in column **sent** are the same and values in **val** are the same and values in **extract** are the same, I need to remove duplicates.

Here is desired output:

```
sent          word     val  extract
   1       good printer   1  printer
   1        bad printer  -1  printer
   1      wireless easy   1 wireless
   2   amazing friendly   1 friendly
   3       well vibrant   1  vibrant
   3   horrible vibrant  -1  vibrant
   4     great notebook   1 notebook
   5           nice car   1      car
```

I'll appreciate any of your help or advice. Many thanks in forward.

Comment: Please check `duplicated` or `unique`

Comment: Basically @akrun already provided all the info you need, though the provided data doesn't look like the one you are actually showing. Not to mention that the desired output is inconsistent. Sometimes you remove the first dupe, in other occasions you remove the second dupe.

Comment: Ok, yes, I see it thanks for your thoughts. !duplicated syntax is what I was looking for. Many thanks Miff and guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the first and second code blocks seem contradictory, so I've gone with the first:

```
> dataFrame <- data.frame(sent = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,5), 
                            word = c("good printer","bad printer","wireless easy","amazing friendly",
                                     "great friendly","quite vibrant nice","well vibrant","no vibrant",
                                     "great notebook","nice car"),
                            val = c(1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
                            extract = c("printer","printer","wireless","friendly","friendly","vibrant",
                                            "vibrant","vibrant","notebook","car"))

> dataFrame[!duplicated(dataFrame[,-2]),]
               sent               word val  extract
            1     1       good printer   1  printer
            2     1        bad printer  -1  printer
            3     1      wireless easy   1 wireless
            4     2   amazing friendly   1 friendly
            6     3 quite vibrant nice   1  vibrant
            9     4     great notebook   1 notebook
            10    5           nice car   1      car
```

Duplicated returns a Boolean vector indicating whether the row has occurred previously, so use this on all the columns that you want to compare, then extract these rows from the original data frame